# Request additional profile fields from Linkedin with ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, linkedin-api

I am creating an external login with Linkedin in my application and so far I have managed to authenticate the user with their corresponding Linkedin account. For the purpose I used the NuGet package `KatanaContrib.Security.LinkedIn` and the following code in `Startup.Auth.cs`.

```
app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(
   apiKey: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LinkedInAPIKey"].ToString(),
   secretKey: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LinkedInAPISecret"].ToString());
```

I successfuly managed to authenticate the user and to make an external registration. However, I want to get all the user information that is provided from LinkedIn in order to save it into my database. In my opinion, the best place to do this will be in the `RegisterExternal` method in the `AccountController` where a new User is created and added to the database. However, when I debug that method I see that not all the available information is returned from LinkedIn.

```
var info = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
var claims = info.ExternalIdentity.Claims;
```

There are only 5 claims returned and when I read the [LinkedIn documentation page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin) I saw that those are exactly the 5 claims correspoding to the basic profile data. Apparently, the external library I am using for Linkedin integration is making request only for the basic profile data and if I want to get more information I need to make request to another url. However, after searching for several hours I still cannot find a way to override that url in order to retrive the data fields I need. Do you have any idea how can I approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue after a long struggle. However, I used the library `Owin.Security.Providers.LinkedIn` instead of `KatanaContrib.Security.LinkedIn` as I found its source code and from there I understood what to do. This is the solution:

```
        var linkedinOptions = new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LinkedInAPIKey"].ToString(),
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LinkedInAPISecret"].ToString(),
            Provider = new LinkedInAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    foreach (var x in context.User)
                    {
                        var claimType = string.Format("urn:linkedin:{0}", x.Key);
                        string claimValue = x.Value.ToString();
                        if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claim => claim.Value == claimValue))
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, claimValue));
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };

        List<string> profileFieldsToGet = new List<string>() { "location" };

        foreach (var field in profileFieldsToGet)
        {
            linkedinOptions.ProfileFields.Add(field);
        }


        app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(linkedinOptions);
```

Now, in `profileFieldsToGet` you can specify which profile fields you want to get. All the basic profile fields can be found [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile).

Comment: How do you access the profile fields in the callback action, from the `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()`?